# Register event on ItemsControl children

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` bound to an `ObservableCollection`. If the user double click one of the items I would like to access the data bound to it so I could edit it. The problem is that since the `Items` are automatically generated by the DataBinding, how could I register events on them?

To makes things a little more clear, here's a quick example:

Class containing the source list:

```
public class SourceClass
{
    public SourceClass()
    {
        ListOfItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ListOfItems
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate >
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Binding code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SourceClass source = new SourceClass();
    source.ListOfItems.Add("Item 1");
    source.ListOfItems.Add("Item 2");
    source.ListOfItems.Add("Item 3");
    source.ListOfItems.Add("Item 4");
    source.ListOfItems.Add("Item 5");

    itemsControl.ItemsSource = source.ListOfItems;
}
```

Comment: 'the Items are automatically generated by the DataBinding' - sounds complicated. Can you post some example code to give us an idea how everything's put together?

Comment: @goobering I edited the question to add a small example

Comment: Just figured I can put the event handler in the data template: <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown" /> This solves the problem.